# Client boostrap - section 'exceeds' its limit

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, row

Folks,

I'm having trouble on my website:
http://clubedebeneficiosunilife.com.br/

There is a section 'Destaques' thumbs with 16 images and a 'Saiba mais' button for each of the 16.

When I open the site on a monitor 15, 17, 19 inches is all normal. OK!

When I open in a cell phone, it's also good. The bootstrap works fine and the 16  thumbs that before were 4x4 ...  pass to 2x8 to fit the smaller cell screen:

Like this link:
http://mobiletest.me/iphone_5_emulator/?u=http://clubedebeneficiosunilife.com.br

It is so perfect.

My problem is when I open a tablet:
http://mobiletest.me/ipad_mini_emulator/?u=http://clubedebeneficiosunilife.com.br

The section 'Destaques' is displaying thumbs in 2x8 (is correct), but note that is extrapolating the container with white background that he should stay inside.

How can I fix the CSS so that the resolution of the tablet does not occur this problem?

I do not have much experience, and I'm with a lot of difficulties in solving this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be really using `container-fluid` class instead of `container`, as the latter has a fixed width and when you place fixed width container within fixed width container it will overflow because of all the paddings, where as `container-fluid` is set to `100%`

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <h2 class="left">Destaques</h2>
    ...
</div>
```

Demonstration of problem:

```css
.container, .container-fluid {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <h1>.container</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>.container</h2>
    <div class="container">
      <h3>.container</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <h1>.container</h1>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <h2>.container-fluid</h2>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <h3>.container-fluid</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/8tkLtjya/